# Wordpress eCommerce

Tags: wordpress, web, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

I am developing online shop and using e-Commerce plugin for wordpress ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce ).
I cannot find table in phpMyAdmin with products and categories.

Could you tell me where information about products and categories storage?
Thnx

Comment: That would depend on the plugin. There are hundreds of ecommerce plugins for WordPress, and they all work differently. If you don't see tables for products and categories, then there probably aren't any. There's no reason products can't be a custom post type, and their categories stored the same way post categories are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Products are stored within wp_posts. As products are a custom post type "wpsc-product" as Dan said.